# Agregar datos a la base de datos php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, registro

Estoy intentando crear un formulario de registro con php mediante PDO + mysql , y todo 'funciona' ya que no muestra ningún error en el localhost, pero se me ejecuta un if que no esperaba, que es el de 'Ya existe el email', cuando consulta el número de filas que hay en la BD. Tampoco se me registran datos en la BD. (es mi primer código php) que es lo que podría estar fallando??

```
archivo config
```

[image: archivo config.php]
datos tabla usuario
[image: usuario]

lo que muestra el local host
[image: localhost]

html.php
[image: html]

```
            <?php
        
        
        
        include 'html.php'; include 'config.php'; if (isset($_POST['registrarse'])) 
            $name_reg=$_POST['name_reg'];
            $lastname_reg=$_POST['lastname_reg'];
            $password_reg=$_POST['password_reg'];
            $password_regconf=$_POST['password_regconf'];
            $direction_reg=$_POST['direction_reg'];
            $city_reg=$_POST['city_reg'];
            $email_reg=$_POST['email_reg'];
            $number_reg=$_POST['number_reg'];
        
            //para saber si el usuario que se va a registrar existe:
            $existente=$base->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='$email_reg'"); 
            //busca en la tabla de usuarios si ya existe el email que se intenta registrar
            if($existente->rowCount()>0) //si da un nº de filas superior a 0, significa que ya esta este email
            {
                echo 'Ya existe el email';
            } 
            else if ($password_reg!=$password_regconf) //comprueba que la pass sea igual
            {
                echo 'Las contraseÃ±as no coinciden';
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    $nuevoUsuario=$base->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, 
                            password, direccion, ciudad, telefono) VALUES (:name_reg, :lastname_reg, :password_reg,
                            :direction_reg, :city_reg, :email_reg, :number_reg");
                    $nuevoUusario->bindParam(':name_reg', $name_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR); //significa q sera
        
         string
                        $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':lastname_reg', $lastname_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':password_reg', $password_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':direction_reg', $direction_reg_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $nuevoUsuario->bindParam('city_reg', $city_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':email_reg', $email_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':number_reg', $number_reg, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        
                        $ejecutar->$nuevoUsuario->execute();
                    } catch (PDOException $error)
                    {
                    print 'ERROR' .$error->getMessage();
                   echo 'Error al registrarse, intentalo de nuevo';
                    }
                    if($ejecutar)//Si se ejecuta correctamente
                    {
                        echo 'Registro realizado con exito';
                    }
                }
            
            
            ?>
```

Comment: Un problema grave en el código es que el primer `if` no tiene llave de apertura ni cierre, eso no es un error, pero cuando es así, solo toma la primera línea debajo de él y las demás quedan fuera del `if`. ¿Es esa la funcionalidad deseada?